# Callback to map function in Angular2 service

Tags: json, typescript

In my service.ts file I have a function (`getQuestions`) that calls a HTTP service that returns a JSON. With this returned JSON (`data`) I want to call another function (`buildQuestions`) so that the result of `buildQuestions` is returned in `getQuestions`.
How do I have to call the functions to return the result of `buildQuestions` or guarantee, that the result of `buildQuestions` is defined when returning it in `getQuestions`.

```
data:any;
questions : QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

getQuestions() {
    let result = this.http.get(this.questionUrl)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(data => {
            this.data = data;
            return this.buildQuestions(data);
    });
    return result; //should actually return "this.buildQuestions(data)" (or "this.questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);")
}

buildQuestions(data){
    for (let key in data) {
        //push Objects in this.questions array
    }
    return this.questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
    data:any;
    questions : QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

    getQuestions() Observable<QuestionsBase[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.questionUrl)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map(data => {
                this.data = data;
                this.buildQuestions(data);
    )};

    buildQuestions(data){
        for (let key in data) {
            //push Objects in this.questions array
        }
        return this.questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
    }
```

Comment: This leads to many errors: Unexpected Token,... You just added`Observable<QuestionsBase[]>`? What was the intention?

Comment: Oh missed the :  getQuestions():  Observable

Comment: Idea is that when you will subscribe to getQuestions it will map to buildQuestions and return result from that.

Comment: It returns an Object that looks like this: `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`
But it should return the array created in `buildQuestions`

Comment: yes and you need to subscribe to it for resolve it. yourMethod().subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)},(err) => console.log(err))